# Why does this code use both useMemo and createSelector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, memoization

[The React-Redux documentation provides this example](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector-examples) for when a selector is used in multiple component instances and depends on the component's props.

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector = () =>
  createSelector(
    state => state.todos,
    (_, isDone) => isDone,
    (todos, isDone) => todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isDone).length
  )

export const TodoCounterForIsDoneValue = ({ isDone }) => {
  const selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone = useMemo(
    makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector,
    []
  )

  const numOfTodosWithIsDoneValue = useSelector(state =>
    selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone(state, isDone)
  )

  return <div>{numOfTodosWithIsDoneValue}</div>
}

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Number of done todos:</span>
      <TodoCounterForIsDoneValue isDone={true} />
      <span>Number of unfinished todos:</span>
      <TodoCounterForIsDoneValue isDone={false} />
    </>
  )
}
```

In the function `TodoCounterForIsDoneValue`, why does the author wrap `makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector` with `useMemo`? My understanding of `createSelector` from `reselect` is that it generates a memoized selector, so what is the purpose of "double" memoizing this selector?

Comment: It's a [parameterized selector](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#parameterized-selector). In the redux doc example they don't pass anything to the selector creator function but you can curry the parameter(s) (see my documentation). When you give each component it's own selector then [memoization will work](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#parameterized-and-memoized).

Comment: Ahh - your 'Parameterized and Memoized' section perfectly helps me understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Because each component needs its own unique instance of the selector for correct memoization behavior.  If many components use the same selector instance, and each pass in their own different arguments (such as `selectThingById(state, props.itemId)`), the selector will never memoize right.  By creating a unique instance per component, each selector can pass in its own separate args and get consistent memoization.

Comment: But isn't that the point of the `makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector` -- it returns a new copy of the numOfTodosWithIsDone selector each time it is called? Why the need to wrap it in `useMemo`? (btw - all your posts online have helped me a bunch in learning Redux. thanks for all your writing!)

Comment: Ahh I understand the necessity of `useMemo` now... Found this excerpt from [@HMR 's notes on selectors useful](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#parameterized-and-memoized):

> Every time Item renders the selectItemById is created again and nothing is memoized because each render re creates the selector. To solve this we can use React.useMemo.

Comment: If the selector is used without a parameter then we don't need useMemo. Am I right?

Comment: This still does not make sense to me. If we put this `const selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone = makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector()` outside the component we would get the same result, right? No need to use memo in this case? We can just use `selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone` directly

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unrelated to the question, but I think in this case, we can use `useCallback` to have the same result w/o having an extra layer of function in `makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector`.

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector = 
  createSelector(
    state => state.todos,
    (_, isDone) => isDone,
    (todos, isDone) => todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isDone).length
  )

export const TodoCounterForIsDoneValue = ({ isDone }) => {
  const selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone = useCallback(
    makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector,
    []
  )

  const numOfTodosWithIsDoneValue = useSelector(state =>
    selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone(state, isDone)
  )

  return <div>{numOfTodosWithIsDoneValue}</div>
}

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Number of done todos:</span>
      <TodoCounterForIsDoneValue isDone={true} />
      <span>Number of unfinished todos:</span>
      <TodoCounterForIsDoneValue isDone={false} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Note, in your example the selector is created in the global scope and therefore will share "cache" with all instances of the same component and will not free the "cache" when unmounted. Also the `useCallback` call seems redundant in this case.